# Gtk3 smooth GtkTreeView on windows

Tags: python, c, gtk3

I have some problems with GTK 3, precisely with GtkTreeView or any other scrollabe widget. GTK+ looks very very bad when scrolling. Flicker happens all the time so I'm looking for some idea to resolve this problem.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a working example of code that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Hello Michael0x2a  if you install the Gtk3 unofficial version for windows available at http://www.tarnyko.net/dl/ (it works fine!) and launch the demo version you will se this flickering effect...imagine something like a skype list of contacts when scrolling you can see multiple re-drawing of the list but on windows only

Comment: when you open a GtkFileChooserDialog for example on windows, and scrolls to the some files, you will see that...

Comment: gtk_widget_add_events(widget, GDK_SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK)  SHOULD ANSWER THIS QESTION (sets it on a GtkScrolledwindows)